# How to display all delivered notifications in react native? Firebase

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to build a notification screen where it lists all the notifications associated with the current user.

I have successfully implemented Firebase to my react native app and Django rest framework backend and can send and receive notifications

But I’m having hard time figuring out how to display all the users notifications. Is that something I take care of in the backend or frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store all your notifications on the backend in your database, and then you just show them on the front.